# Deleting rows with multiple text

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete rows where the following text is between columns A and Z:

- "Customer Statement"
- "Customer No:'
- "date"

This should search from Row 11 onward

This does not seems to work:

```
Sub Deleterowsmultiplename()
    Cells.Find(What:="Customer Statement").Offset(1, 0).Resize(5, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Should all three statements occur for the row to be deleted?  Will the text always be in the same column, or could it move about?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim row As Long

For row = Rows.Count To 11 Step -1
    If Not Range(Cells(row, 1), Cells(row, 26)).Find("Customer Statement") Is Nothing Then
    If Not Range(Cells(row, 1), Cells(row, 26)).Find("Customer No:") Is Nothing Then
    If Not Range(Cells(row, 1), Cells(row, 26)).Find("date") Is Nothing Then
        Rows(row).entireRow.Delete
    End If
    End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Since you want it to run throught all rows in a sheet, this will take a while (around 10 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

The use of `On Error Resume Next` is not the cleanest, but it will get the job done. Be mindful that there is no specification to what sheet this should be applied to, so it will be done on `Activesheet`.

```
Sub Deleterowsmultiplename()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim WhattoFind As Variant
    Dim myRng As Range


    WhattoFind = Array("Customer Statement", "Customer No:", "date")
    Set myRng = Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(1048576, 26))
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(WhattoFind) To UBound(WhattoFind)
        myRng.Find(What:=WhattoFind(i)).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Improved and with proper Error Handling

```
Sub Deleterowsmultiplename()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim WhattoFind As Variant
    Dim myRng As Range


    WhattoFind = Array("Customer Statement", "Customer No:", "date")
    Set myRng = Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(1048576, 26))
    For i = LBound(WhattoFind) To UBound(WhattoFind)
        Do
        On Error GoTo NextName
        myRng.Find(What:=WhattoFind(i)).EntireRow.Delete
        Loop
NextName:
    Resume NextName2
NextName2:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: An answer that is based on `On Error Resume Next` (with no effort to check for or handle error) teaches bad programming practice. The abuse of that statement is the source of numerous bugs. Don't teach a new VBA programmer to use that statement, especially in this blanket way (turn off error-handling and hope for the best).

Comment: That's very valid criticism. I'll keep it in mind for future answers.

Comment: Dear @dadler, This only delete the first occurence of these text, Below occurences, Still remains the same and are not deleted, Casn you please help

Comment: @JohnColeman would you mind giving me your input on the edit? Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @JenitaC , see my Edit

Comment: Downvote changed to an upvote. The problem with `On Error Resume Next` on Stack Overflow is that several times a week (no exaggeration) an Excel VBA question is asked which involves a bug which is hidden by a blanket use of that construct. I've taken to referring to it as `On Error Hide Bug`, which is how many people use it. Your use was borderline okay, but wasn't really safe enough for Stack Overflow (where some readers might see it and decide to adopt it in their code in a less safe way).